# Trying to login to my wordpress blog redirect me to a weird page

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

Im trying to login to my wordpress website by adding `/wp-admin/` it worked a while ago but now when I add it it redirect me to this webpage `www.mywebsite.com/cgi-sys/index.html`
so My question is why this happend. and how can I login to my account again.

Comment: Did you try with `yoursite.com/wp-login.php`?

Comment: @ShaktiSingh yes I did, and it redirect me to the same page /cgi-sys/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Possibly what has happened is your WordPress site is set to another site. What you can do to fix this is go into your WordPress database and do the following:

Note: You may need to replace the `wp` in `wp_options` with your site prefix. Check your wp-config.php if you're not sure of your prefix.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name='siteurl' OR option_name='home';
```

This should return something to the following:

```
+-----------+---------+-------------+--------------------+----------+
| option_id | blog_id | option_name | option_value       | autoload |
+-----------+---------+-------------+--------------------+----------+
|         3 |       0 | siteurl     | http://hexcoder.us | yes      |
|        39 |       0 | home        | http://hexcoder.us | yes      |
+-----------+---------+-------------+--------------------+----------+
```

In my case, this is correct as my site is in fact `http://hexcoder.us` but in your case is should be the URL for your website. Assuming this is the problem, running the following query should fix your problem:

Note: Depending on your desired site settings, you may need to change the permalink settings in your admin panel later.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value='http://your-site-url' WHERE option_name='siteurl' OR option_name='home';
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell your Wordpress administrator to update the plugin "**Adminimize**".